# How to use Bootstrap components from within Markdown files in Pelican?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, markdown, pelican

What is the best way to use Boostrap components (e.g., [labels](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) and [alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)) from within Markdown? The Pelican [twitter_bootstrap_rst_directives](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/twitter_bootstrap_rst_directives) seems to provide the right functionality, but for RST files.

Comment: The Pelican plugin [md_inline_extension](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/md_inline_extension) goes partway to giving the needed functionality. It allows custom Markdown extensions for including arbitrary "span" elements.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Markdown does not provide such functionality. In fact, there is no such thing as "directives" in Markdown. As stated in the original [Syntax Rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format for writing for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

That being the case, you can just insert the HTML required by Bootstrap directly into your document.

> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g. `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. — must be separated from surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the block should not be indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart enough not to add extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level tags.

That said, you can develop your own extensions to Markdown and create your own "directives." In fact, if you are using Pelican, it relies on the [Python-Markdown](http://packages.python.org/Markdown/) for Markdown parsing and Python-Markdown has an [Extension API](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html) which allows you to develop your own extensions (see a [tutorial here](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Tutorial:-Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown)). Of course, you may want to check the list of [third-party extension](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions) to see if anyone else has already created such an extension.

If not, and you decide to create your own, might I suggest using HTML comments as the syntax for directives. That way, if/when your documents are parsed with a Markdown parser which does not support your custom syntax, the directives will not break the parser and pass through unaffected. Given that Pelican already includes support for such functionality for Rst, there is existing interest within that community. If you ask that community, there might be some interest/help in developing a reasonable syntax for directives.